# VBSCript Error as "Non-negetive number required"

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I wrote the below code to remove some elements from the `ArrayList` objects depending on the Match of some elements in an 1D Array. But getting an **ERROR** as `Non-negetive number required` to the line `ArrayListTaskDetails.RemoveRange RemovePosition, 4`. But what I know is `IndexOf()` returns `0 - based` index when match found and `-1` for unmatched. Then why the error is coming?

**Code:**

```
For IndexSearch = Lbound(VMHArray) To Ubound(VMHArray)
    Do Until ArrayListTaskDetails.IndexOf(VMHArray(IndexSearch), 0) <> -1
        RemovePosition = ArrayListTaskDetails.IndexOf(VMHArray(IndexSearch), 0)
        ArrayListTaskDetails.RemoveRange RemovePosition, 4
    Loop
Next
```

Comment: Is this VBA or vbscript?  Regardless, I think you want to change `Until` to `While` or change `<>` to `=`.  Finally, what are you trying to accomplish?  The code looks rather confused.  You're querying the list to find the index of the item located at index IndexSearch.  It doesn't make sense; it's like asking "what is the address of the building located at 1 Main Street?".

Comment: @phoog I used `until` by intention as the any array element can be present in the ArrayList more than once. But according to the `MSDN` defination for IndexOf() it returns the `0 based index` for the first found, and `-1` for unmatched,then how such `negetive number` except `-1` comes? any idea? Id Used `while` then I cant remove array element which are present in the `ArrayList` in totally.Only one will be removed I believe. Correct me If I wrong!

Comment: @phoog I agree with you, But the mistake I did is wrongly placed `<>` instead of `=`. And I just corrected it. Hope now it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the "doesn't make sense" part of my comment was wrong; I misread the example.

Here's what's happening: `Do Until X` means evaluate X, and if the result is *false*, then execute the loop body.  So, IndexOf is clearly returning -1, the "Until" condition evaluates to false, and the loop body executes, with RemovePosition being equal to -1.  That explains the error.

Comment: Yeah!b you are right and I fixed it ! Thanks for your effort and help! :-)

Comment: I got another error in other part,Can I continue here or different post you would suugest?

Comment: @VBSlover If it's another error in another part, it should probably be a new question.